# Identifying entities for a scenario

Tags: database, database-design

Here is the scenario :

"A placement agency which extends its services to organizations and individuals. Candidates register their details like personal, academics, skill set and experience. Organizations give their requirements in terms of skill set, qualification, experience etc. The agency maintains a website through which registration can be done. Site also allows updating candidate profiles and organization requirements. It also gives facility to search job and suitable candidates."

What would be the entities here?

Answer (score 0):

Entities are usually the nouns in the scenario description.

Not every noun becomes an entity:

- They will vary depending on you level of normalisation
  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
- Some nouns may become attributes of an entity
- Some nouns may become business logic components rather than entities.

More info on Mapping from natural language is on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Mapping_natural_language

Answer (score -2):

1. Agency
2. Candidates
3. Organizations
4. Website

My guess is this

Comment: Could you explain why?